# How to access dynamically value of an array from API Response in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I'm not really good with array, and need some help,

I need to specifically retrieve only "value" from this given array, 
for example of this given array below, I only need the "40000" value.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "service" => "OKE"
    "description" => "Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis"
    "cost" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "value" => 40000
        "etd" => "2-3"
        "note" => ""
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "service" => "REG"
    "description" => "Layanan Reguler"
    "cost" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "value" => 48000
        "etd" => "1-2"
        "note" => ""
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "service" => "YES"
    "description" => "Yakin Esok Sampai"
    "cost" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "value" => 72000
        "etd" => "1-1"
        "note" => ""
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I've been trying to use `array_search` `array_key_exists` ,and many more array functions, but still no luck..

I've achieved this result before by this code

```
 $costsOKE = $costObj['rajaongkir']['results'][0]['costs'][0]['cost'][0]['value']; //OKE
$costsREG = $costObj['rajaongkir']['results'][0]['costs'][1]['cost'][0]['value']; //REG
$costsYES = $costObj['rajaongkir']['results'][0]['costs'][2]['cost'][0]['value']; //YES
```

the problem is this is too static, because sometimes it doesnt always have "OKE" or "YES"

I don't know how to specifically check with certain "key" of an array

like,

```
if(0['service'] == 'OKE') //I already have input field for service
{
 $value = ??? //should be 40000 here and this is what I need
}
```

how to achieve this with most simple method?

thanks before

Comment: I would recommend reading through [the PHP manual about arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Btw, the array you've posted doesn't have any keys named `rajaongkir`, `results` or `costs` which you're using in your examples. Have you only pasted a partial of the complete array? If yes, please post the complete array or we won't have a clue what the structure actually looks like.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've been reading and trying for a while.. but I got deadline ..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes actually, you right, but the ```$costObj``` I post is actually the result after I did the looping, to access the array key deeper.. it was quite a long trial and error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a built in helper `Arr::get()` for pulling nested values from arrays using 'dot notation'. 
[Laravel 6.x Arr::get() docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-get)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$costsOKE = Arr::get($costObj, 'rajaongkir.results.0.costs.0.cost.0.value');//OKE
$costsREG = Arr::get($costObj, 'rajaongkir.results.0.costs.1.cost.0.value');//REG
$costsYES = Arr::get($costObj, 'rajaongkir.results.0.costs.2.cost.0.value');//YES
```

Or from the array you gave:

```
$costsOKE = Arr::get($costObj, '0.cost.0.value');//OKE
$costsREG = Arr::get($costObj, '1.cost.0.value');//REG
$costsYES = Arr::get($costObj, '2.cost.0.value');//YES
```

The result will be `null` if the value does not exist.

For Laravel <= 5.6, you can use `array_get` instead.

Comment: thank you so much, this is the answer I looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try do it this way:

```php
function getValueFromArray($arr, $key)
{
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ( $key === $item['service'] ) {
            return $item['cost'][0]['value'];
        }
    }
}

$value = getValueFromArray($costObj['rajaongkir']['results'][0]['costs'], 'OKE');
```

But note that this function will be applicable just for your array structure. If structure changes, it might not work.